# Threads not working properly

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, task

I've the following code, used to test the Task framework on C#

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
            Task<string> task1 = AsyncA();
            task1.ContinueWith(Print);

            Task<string> task2 = AsyncB();
            task2.ContinueWith(Print);

            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] {task1, task2});
   }

   static async Task<string> AsyncA()
   {
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            return "A";
   }

   static async Task<string> AsyncB()
   {
            Thread.Sleep(430);
            return "B";
   }

   static async void Print(Task<string> str)
   {
            Console.WriteLine(str.Result);
   }
```

My output is the following:

> A
>      B

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep` in `async` code. Use `Task.Delay` instead

Comment: @Trey He was expecting `B A` because `A` sleeps for longer than `B`.

Comment: Read your compiler warnings. The compiler is giving you a warning that tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are running the methods `AsyncA` and `AsyncB` synchronously. If you are using `async` you need to `await` the end of a task. Change your methods to

```
static async Task<string> AsyncA()
{
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    return "A";
}

static async Task<string> AsyncB()
{
    await Task.Delay(430);    
    return "B";
}
```

and you will get your expected output of

> B
> A

For further reference have a look on [the MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

**EDIT:**

For the sake of completeness you should also change the `Print` method in the same manner, otherwise it also is running synchronously up to now.
Since in this method you get the task via the parameter you can actually await the result directly in the `Console.WriteLine` method:

```
static async void Print(Task<string> str)
{
    Console.WriteLine(await str);
}
```

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. Made exactly the same mistake, when I started to use async await ;)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when using asynchronous methods, it's generally more accepted to use the awaitable `Task.Delay(ms)` rather than `Thread.Sleep(ms)`.

In the MSDN documentation, the `ContinueWith(task)` method:

> Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes.

For this reason, only once `task1` is completed, it will execute the remainder of the code - this is why your ouput is A B rather than B A.
By using `Task.Delay(ms)` and awaiting the methods as opposed to using `ContinueWith(task)`, you'll get your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!